# Asignar variables de acuerdo a un array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

necesito ayuda con para darle un valor booleano a unas variables dependiendo de un array.

Este es el array

```
{dashboard_admin_view: "0", employee_add: "0", employee_del: "1", employee_edi: "0", employee_view: "0", group_add: "0", group_del: "1", group_edi: "1"....}
```

Y necesito darle un valor booleano a las variables que tienen el mismo nombre dependiendo del valor del array, me refiero a que si el valor de la llave `employee_del` es `1` me asigne la variable employee_del a true y si la llave `group_add` es `0` que me asigne a la variable group_add a false.

Esto con el fin de mostrar con check o sin el check varios checkbox.

Aqui tengo este codigo pero no me funciona correctamente.

```
        this.checkbox = [
          {
            name: 'Empleados',
            employee_view: rsp[2].employee_view, 
            employee_add: rsp[2].employee_add, 
            employee_edi: rsp[2].employee_edit, 
            employee_del: rsp[2].employee_del, 
            user_add: rsp[2].user_add, 
            user_edit: rsp[2].user_edit, 
            group_add: rsp[2].group_add, 
            group_edi: rsp[2].group_edit, 
            group_del: rsp[2].group_del, 
            transfer_messages: rsp[2].transfer_messages, 
            transfer_messages_np: rsp[2].transfer_messages_np, 
            dashboard_admin_view: rsp[2].dashboard_admin_view
          }
        ];
        
        
        for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(this.checkbox)) {
          let v=Number(value);
          let a = Boolean(v);
          this.checkbox[key] = a;
        }
          console.log(this.checkbox)
```

Cualquier ayuda que me puedan brindar se los agradeceré.

Comment: que resultado te muestra el  `console.log(this.checkbox)`

Comment: Me sale `Array(1)0: false`

Comment: es que es un `arreglo` no un `objecto` por ende debes pasarle `Object.entries(this.checkbox[0])` y a la hora de la asignacion `this.checkbox[0][key] = a;` y luego `console.log(this.checkbox[0])` saludos.

Comment: Oh si, muchas gracias amigo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

puedes hacerlo asi:

version clasica:

```js
var array = {dashboard_admin_view: "0", employee_add: "0", employee_del: "1", employee_edi: "0", employee_view: "0", group_add: "0", group_del: "1", group_edi: "1"}


for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(array)) {
        // version legible
        // convertimos a entero:
        // podemos usar tambien parseInt(value)
        let v=Number(value);
        // pasamos a booleano
        v = Boolean(v);
        array[key] = v;
}
console.log(array)
```

version corta:

```js
    var array = {dashboard_admin_view: "0", employee_add: "0", employee_del: "1", employee_edi: "0", employee_view: "0", group_add: "0", group_del: "1", group_edi: "1"}


    for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(array)) {
            // version corta
            // ! convierte a bool y niega !true = false 
            // negar 2 veces regresa !!true = true
            // + antes de la varibale es igual a Number(v)
            array[key] = !!+value;
    }
    console.log(array)
```

Comment: Hola, estoy haciendo este codigo para un proyecto en angular y de las dos maneras en las que lo  enviaste me retorna un array false, asi tengo el codigo.

```
this.checkbox = [
          {
            name: 'Empleados',
            employee_view: rsp[2].employee_view, 
            employee_add: rsp[2].employee_add, 
          }
        ];
        
        
        for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(this.checkbox)) {
          let v=Number(value);
          let a = Boolean(v);
          this.checkbox[key] = a;
        }
        console.log(this.checkbox)
```

Comment: @Alexis debes editar tu pregunta y colocar el codigo como lo tienes ya que esto es totalmente diferente a lo que colocaste en tu pregunta.
saludos.

Comment: Ok ya lo cambie, intente resumirlo pero creo que me equivoque, disculpa

Answer (score 0):

Prueba el código de esta forma

```
var array = {dashboard_admin_view: "0", employee_add: "0", employee_del: "1", employee_edi: "0", employee_view: "0", group_add: "0", group_del: "1", group_edi: "1"}


for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(array)) {
          
    if (value == 0) {
        array.employee_add=false;
        array.employee_edi=false;
        array.employee_del=false;
        array.group_add=false;
        array.group_edi=false;
        array.group_del=false;
        array.dashboard_admin_view=false;
    }else{
      
        array.employee_add=true;
        array.employee_edi=true;
        array.employee_del=true;
        array.group_add=true;
        array.group_edi=true;
        array.group_del=true;
        array.dashboard_admin_view=true;
    }
    
}

console.log(array);

// salida
/*
 {
  dashboard_admin_view: true,
  employee_add: true,
  employee_del: true,
  employee_edi: true,
  employee_view: '0',
  group_add: true,
  group_del: true,
  group_edi: true
}
 */
```

Comment: Hola, de esta manera lastimosamente no me funciona, igualmente muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responderme